# AppBundle\\Entity\\User#$class_cat\", got \"integer\" instead

Tags: symfony

**Hi i got this error while data insert in database please let me know where is the problem i am new in symfony**

> "Expected value of type \"AppBundle\Entity\Class_cat\" for
>   association field \"AppBundle\Entity\User#$class_cat\", got
>   \"integer\" instead.",
>                   "class": "Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException"

**this is User entity**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->class_cat = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $role;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Class_cat", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="class_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $class_cat;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getClassCat()
    {
        return $this->class_cat;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $class_cat
     */
    public function setClassCat($class_cat)
    {
        $this->class_cat = $class_cat;
    }
```

this is class_cat enity

```
class Class_cat {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="class_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $className;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="class_cat")
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set className
     *
     * @param string $className
     *
     * @return Class_cat
     */
    public function setClassName($className)
    {
        $this->className = $className;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get className
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getClassName()
    {
        return $this->className;
    }


    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $users
     */
    public function setUsers($users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }
```

**this is controller code**

```
>  public function postAction(Request $request)
>     {
>         $data = new User;
>         $name = $request->get('name');
>         $role = $request->get('role');
>         $class = $request->get('class_id');
>         if (empty($name) || empty($role) || empty($class)) {
>             return new View("NULL VALUES ARE NOT ALLOWED", Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
>         }
>         $data->setName($name);
>         $data->setRole($role);
>         $data->setClassId(1);
>         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
>         $em->persist($data);
>         $em->flush();
>         return new View("User Added Successfully", Response::HTTP_OK);
>     }
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache with `php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod` after you made your Entity changes? The Entities look ok.

Comment: Please show us how you create/insert the new entity.

Comment: Alvin Bunk @ let me try

Comment: Himal@ created with cmd..php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity

Comment: AlvinBunk @ i have cleared the cache and regenerate the entity but prblm still coming

Comment: Your value for `class_cat` needs to be the entity/object  itself and not the id/primary key of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the entity not the id for example:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$classCat = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ClassCat')->find(1);
$data->setClassCat($classCat);
```

Comment: can u plz explain where i did wrong is there any mistake to create entity.

Comment: You need to pass an entity not an integer, doctrine needs an entity in this case. If this solved your problem accept the answer to help other persons with your same problem. Thanks @shazzAbbasi

Comment: Hi, I am willing to approach this way, wont this cost extra db access?. Is there any better way? any documentation for support for your answer pls.

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of passing integer value you need to pass an object of class `Class_cat`.
When you mapped any entity field to any other entity symfony need object to set.
So your solution is simple to try something like this:

```
public function postAction(Request $request){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $data = new User;
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $role = $request->get('role');
    $class = $request->get('class_id');

    if (empty($name) || empty($role) || empty($class)) {
        return new View("NULL VALUES ARE NOT ALLOWED", 
        Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }

    $classCat = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ClassCat')->find($class);
    $data->setName($name);
    $data->setRole($role);
    $data->setClassId($classCat);
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();
   return new View("User Added Successfully", Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of integer value in 
use object like this:

```
$data->setClassId(1);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$classCat = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ClassCat')->find(1);

$data->setClassCat($classCat);
```